# unexpected token ILLEGAL in underscore.js

Tags: javascript

```
<%
var cache_badge = '';
for (var i=0; i<badges.length; i++)
{
     cache_badge += " <a href='' data-toggle='popover' data-content='test' data-original-title='test'><img style='padding-right:10px' class='thumb' src='img/badges/" + badges[i].image + "' /></a>;
}
%>
```

This throws an error saying unexpected token ILLEGAL. It worked fine until I added the data toggle content and originaltitle attributes. What in there could be causing the problems?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try changing

```
src='img/badges/" + badges[i].image + "' /></a>;
```

to

```
src='img/badges/" + badges[i].image + "' /></a>";
```

you didn't close your string

Comment: Thanks! Can't believe I missed that